# Netsuite API to fetch Items in PHP

Tags: php, api, product, netsuite

I have downloaded Nesuite API for PHP from following link: `https://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-sample-applications.shtml`
But I could not find any file to fetch product data.

Anyone help me how to fetch product data from netsuite API ?

**Edited**

I have downloaded NetSuite API for PHP. There are some files to get customer,add order etc. But I can not find any file to fetch product data from Netsuite. Anyone know the code or file to fetch product data ?

I need just hint .Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now Netsuite provides REST API to fetch items from netsuite ERP.
Here is the link to fetch inventory items from Netsuite using REST API in PHP

http://www.itguruz.com/netsuite-rest-api/netsuite-php-authorization/